# npm でパッケージのローカルインストールが急に動作しなくなった

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

npmを使用して約半年になります。

先日、npmでパッケージのローカルインストールがうまく動作しなくなったため、
直すために助言をいただきたいです。

Windows10でnpm+webpackを用いた開発をしていたんですが、
追加でclean webpack pluginをインストールしたところ、
インストール直後からnpm-scriptsでwebpackが動作しなくなりました。

```
'webpack' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

以下、直すために試みたことです。

- clean webpack pluginをインストールする前の状態に戻し(git)、`npm i`を実行
- webpack他関連パッケージをグローバルにインストール
- Node.jsの完全削除後、再インストールし`npm i`を実行
- Node.js、npmのバージョンアップ

ローカルのnode_modulesを確認したところ、webpack他関連パッケージのファイルが存在せず、
試しに新しくプロジェクトを作成し`npm init -y & npm i -D webpack`を実行したところ、以下のファイルが生成されました（中身はすべて空です）。

```
node_modules
├─@jridgewell
├─@types
├─@webassemblyjs
├─@xtuc
└─.package-lock.json
```

グローバルでwebpackのインストールを行うと、%APPDATA%\npm内にwebpackのファイルは生成されます。

他のPCでプロジェクトをクローンし、`npm i`を行ったところ、
他のPCでは正常にパッケージのローカルインストールができました。

そして、他のPCで生成されたnode_modulesを不具合の起きているPCにコピーしたところ、
正常に動くようになりました。

ただ、毎回パッケージのインストールをほかの端末で行うわけにもいかないため、
どうしても直したいと思っています。

長文になり失礼いたしました。
ご協力お願いします。

Comment: 補足：node.js再インストール後のそれぞれのバージョンは以下の通りです（node: 18.12.1, npm: 9.2.0）

Answer (score 1):

自己解決

他のユーザーだと**何故か**ローカルインストールが正常に出来たため、
runasコマンドで他のユーザーでコマンドプロンプトを立ち上げるバッチを作成した。

```
runas /savecred /user:<<ユーザー名>> cmd
```

直接的な解決には至っていないので、
原因が分かる方がいましたら助言よろしくお願いします。